# Semantic URL for Rest API to query a list object

Tags: rest, api, web-services

I had a simple rest API to return get a list of categories, path is **/categories**

```
[
    {id: 1, name: "category 1"},
    {id: 2, name: "category 2"},
    {id: 3, name: "category 3"},
    {id: 4, name: "category 4"},
    {id: 5, name: "category 5"},
    {id: 6, name: "category 6"}
]
```

Now I want to use GET method to query a list of categories by Ids, for example, If I want to get the categories 1,3,4, the path could be: /categories?id=[1,3,4]. 
Is someone can help me a good semantic url in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like the convention suggested in [Restful Web Services](http://a.co/02vspqc)

> Use punctuation characters to separate multiple pieces of data at the same level of a hierarchy.  Use commas when the order of items matters.... Use semicolons when the order doesn't matter.

More broadly, you may want to look into the possibilities described in [RFC 6570 URI Templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570)